# c# How to block Enter key?

Tags: c#, block, enter

I have two buttons.
When I start my api and hit Enter then api doing code from buuton1.
How to block it?

```
private void frm2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {

    }...
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read the description of the `block` tag you applied to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can block a key by setting SuppresKeyPress to `true` in your event handler `frm2_KeyPress`:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Please note I have changed `e.KeyChar` to `e.KeyCode` as personally I find `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter` more readible than `(e.KeyChar == (char)13)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KeyPressEventargs.Handled property for this.

```
private void frm2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

For more information, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx